# How to encrypt files with AES256-GCM in golang?

Tags: encryption, go, block-cipher

AES256-GCM could be implemented in go as https://gist.github.com/cannium/c167a19030f2a3c6adbb5a5174bea3ff

However, `Seal` method of interface `cipher.AEAD` has signature:

```
Seal(dst, nonce, plaintext, additionalData []byte) []byte
```

So for very large files, one must read all file contents into memory, which is unacceptable.

A possible way is to implement `Reader`/`Writer` interfaces on `Seal` and `Open`, but shouldn't that be solved by those block cipher "modes" of AEAD? So I wonder if this is a design mistake of golang cipher lib, or I missed something important with GCM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AEADs should not be used to encrypt large amounts of data in one go. The API is designed to discourage this.

Encrypting large amounts of data in a single operation means that a) either all the data has to be held in memory or b) the API has to operate in a streaming fashion, by returning unauthenticated plaintext.

Returning unauthenticated data is dangerous it's [not
hard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95920/encrypt-tar-gz-file-on-create) to find people on the internet suggesting things like `gpg -d your_archive.tgz.gpg | tar xz`because the gpg command also provides a streaming interface.

With constructions like AES-GCM it's, of course, very easy to
manipulate the plaintext at will if the application doesn't
authenticate it before processing. Even if the application is careful
not to "release" plaintext to the UI until the authenticity has been
established, a streaming design exposes more program attack surface.

By normalising large ciphertexts and thus streaming APIs, the next
protocol that comes along is more likely to use them without realising
the issues and thus the problem persists.

Preferably, plaintext inputs would be chunked into reasonably large
parts (say 16KiB) and encrypted separately. The chunks only need to be
large enough that the overhead from the additional authenticators is
negligible. With such a design, large messages can be incrementally
processed without having to deal with unauthenticated plaintext, and
AEAD APIs can be safer. (Not to mention that larger messages can be
processed since AES-GCM, for one, has a 64GiB limit for a single
plaintext.)

Some thought is needed to ensure that the chunks are in the correct
order, i.e. by counting nonces, that the first chunk should be first, i.e. by starting the nonce at zero, and that the last chunk should be
last, i.e. by appending an empty, terminator chunk with special
additional data. But that's not hard.

For an example, see the chunking used in [miniLock](https://web.archive.org/web/20170225215055/https://github.com/kaepora/miniLock#-minilock).

Even with such a design it's still the case that an attacker can cause
the message to be detectably truncated. If you want to aim higher, an
all-or-nothing transform can be used, although that requires two
passes over the input and isn't always viable.

Comment: Thanks! As a suggestion, I think this explanation could be added to golang docs.

Comment: Link to miniLock is giving *"404 - Page not found"*.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a design mistake. It's just that the API is incomplete in that regard.

GCM is a streaming mode of operation and therefore able to handle encryption and decryption on demand without stopping the stream. It seems that you cannot reuse the same AEAD instance with the previous MAC state, so you cannot directly use this API for GCM encryption.

You could implement your own GCM on top of `crypto.NewCTR` and your own implementation of GHASH.